# Default groups for GroupBy linq method

Tags: c#, list, linq, collections, group-by

Is there a way to define default groups when using GroupBy method. It is only used when there is no item for that group.

Lets say this collection `[-4, -3, -2, -1, 0]` should be divided into three groups `a, b, c` if they are negative, zero and positive. And finally each group should be counted like `[4, 1, 0]`

```
myCollection.GroupBy(p=>p<0?"a":p==0?"b":"c").Select(p=>p.Count()).ToArray()
```

Can it be that group `c` also exists without any item.

Any other one-liner linq is also suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add three items with known groupings, and then factor them out, like this:

```
var counts = myCollection
    .Concat(new[] { int.MinValue, 0, int.MaxValue }) // Add items to force groups
    .GroupBy(p => p<0?"a":p==0?"b":"c")
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count()-1);
```

Note `g.Count() - 1` expression, it is there to undo the effect of concatenating with an array that forces the default items.

In a more complicated scenario when you need groups themselves, rather than simple counts, you would need to concatenate special "placeholder" objects with the input, and then filter them out after performing `GroupBy`.

Comment: This is much better to create another data structure. What do you mean by placeholder? In my case objects are students with grade property (which should be grouped based on). If I want to keep the students under groups, how can I mark those fake students (I assume you mean that by placeholder)

Comment: nevermind, I found a way to filter them out. simply by giving specific names.